# What is the best way to store user Follow Relationship in Redux in Normalized form?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I m building a kind of social network, where users can follow each other, but i can't figure out which is the best way to store the user follow user relationship in redux, i have basically 2 ways, which one is good, ? i will also implement realtime updates for follow unfollow button,

```
entities : {
    usersById : {
        userId : {
             isFollowedByMe : true/false
         }
    }
}
```

or a complete different map

```
entities : {
    usersById : {
        /*   */
    } 
},
relationships : {
    userFollowMap : {
        targetUserId : true,
        anotherTargetUserId : false,
    }
}
```

server is also own by me, so i can send data in normalized form to client without any problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Redux doesn't force you to use normalized form. And this question goes way beyond redux.

Picking the right schema is always a tradeoff between normalization and optimization and heavily depends on what particular feature you want to implement.

If you only want to show if the current user of the app follows the user displayed on the screen the 1st way is fine. But maybe you also want to show all followed users on another page, if that's you case then both implementations proposed by you are bad for this because they require you to filter the array of all users to get the ones that followed by you. And in this case, you would want to have a `followedByMe` array with all ids of users followed by you.

But since data stored in redux share it's lifetime with the app you are much more agile than with the data in a persistent store such as a database. You can use both `isFollowedByMe` field and `followedByMe` list to implement both features effectively. Also, frontend is much more durable to refactorings and changes. That makes you able to experiment with low cost. So you can use some schema and if it doesn't fit your need at some point you can just refactor without any migrations and stuff. So don't be afraid to use something that is suitable for you right now.

But don't use the same approach to your backend and database schema, they are harder to refactor.